# jquery show/hide and opacity

Tags: jquery, opacity

Here is my lehmans terms of what i am trying to accomplish.

i will have 3 100x100 px divs, floated left.

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="1">did you know?</div>
     <div id="2">help</div>
     <div id="3">other</div>
</div>
```

when you hover or mouse over either of these 3 divs another div will appear via show(); or slideDown(); with the content specific to that topic.

question is, is there a way to make it so that when you hover over any of the divs 1,2,3, the other two will lower opacity to make them look transparen?

that part i am unable to figure out...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First here, make sure those IDs are valid, e.g. not starting with a number (unless you're on a HTML5 doctype).

Then you can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), like this:

```
$("#container > div").css({opacity: 0.2 }).hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.2 }); 
});
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/E96nP/), the initial [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) call is to make them all non-hovered-ish on page load.

---

For a more complete demo, showing the content as well, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/E96nP/2/) :)

Here's that example markup:

```
<div id="container">
     <div>did you know?</div>
     <div>help</div>
     <div>other</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div>Did You Know? Content</div>
    <div>Help Content</div>
    <div>Some other stuff</div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$("#container > div").css({opacity: 0.2 }).hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
  $("#content div").eq($(this).index()).stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.2 });
  $("#content div").eq($(this).index()).stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

You can adjust it of course to leave the last hovered one open, etc...it's just an idea for an effect the way you descibe.

Comment: I think you need a `.stop(true, true)` before the `slideDown()` and also before `slideUp()` to avoid the animation queue buildup

Comment: @Russ - Good call, I wasn't looking for queue on these, always a nice addition...it all depends on what he's after, it sounds like he has some sort of effect already, I'm unsure by the question if this is even useful, hopefully it will be to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
div.onmouseover = function() {
    for(i = 0, c = this.parentNode.childNodes, e = c.length; i < e; i++) {
        if (c[i] !== this) {
            $(c[i]).css('opacity', '...');
        }
    }
}
```